Frida session.detach stuch forever
I use Frida with python and load JS script
Sometimes the session.detach() stuch forever, why is that ?
import frida
remote_device = frida.get_device_manager().add_remote_device(f"{IP}:{PORT}")
session = remote_device.attach(PID)


script = session.create_script(open(SCRIPT_PATH).read())

script.on("message", my_message_handler)
script.load()

try:
    stdin.read()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
print('TRY TO DETACH')
session.detach()
print('EXIT.....')


What is the target platform you hook processes/apps on? Yes that can happen especially if something goes wrong. One pitfall are callbacks from Frida like the my_message_handler you have defined in your code. To my experience such callbacks are best very short without code that takes much time. best is using it to start a new thread and performing any operations there.
